# How to retrieval array from postgresql using C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, postgresql, database-connection, npgsql

I have a table in postgresql database some like this: `tbl`, let include a field `fcth` that its datatype is `double[]`. I want return a multiple rows of this field and store in a list `List<double[]>` in C#.

### My Sample table as:

### id          fcth

### 1     {1, 1, 4, 2, 0, 0, 4}

### 2     {2, 2, 0, 4, 1, 4, 2}

### 3     {4, 4, 2, 1, 1, 0, 3}

And I have the following code:

```
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "tbl");
        List<double[]> od = new List<double[]>();
        foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables["tbl"].Rows)
        { 
            od.Add(Convert.ToDouble[](row["fcth"].ToString()));
            dr.Read();
        }
```

But, I got an error from `Convert.ToDouble[]`. How can I solve it?

Comment: Did you try using sql to select from the table?

Comment: show us db schema, sample data and expected output to have a better idea what you have/need. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: please clarify the question with example

Comment: OK. I changed my question and explained with simple example.

Answer (score 0):

What is the data type of the column 'fcth' in the table ?

let me suggest you one small thing.
Change the following code :
od.Add(Convert.ToDouble);

To : 
var temp = row["fcth"].ToString();
od.Add(Convert.ToDouble);

and see the value of temp, you will find the issue.